# Haskell create vector with subvectors using indexes

Tags: haskell, vector, haskell-vector

I'm trying to create a vector with subvectors consisting of elements taken out from another vector using a vector of sub-vector indexes.
Each element in `b` corresponds to the sub-vector-index the elements in `a` should have when put into `c`.

```
import Data.Vector
let a = fromList [9,2,3,7,4,1,8,5]
let b = fromList [3,3,2,0,1,1,2,2]
let c = fromList [ a ! k | k <- b ]
Expected c = [[7],[4,1],[3,8,5],[9,2]]
```

I'm a bit stuck, getting the error

> "Could not match expected type [Int] with actual type Vector Integer
>   in stmt list comprehension 
>   k <- b"

Comment: Are you looking for [`backpermute`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/candidate/docs/Data-Vector.html#g:17)?

Comment: No, in backpermute the index vector contains the indexes of the values that should be taken from `a`, but my index vector `b` contains the sub-list indexes where the elements should be put.

Comment: Pretty sure you're not going to get that behavior without fiddling with ST and intermediate mutable vectors yourself; I wouldn't expect that to be built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work since `b` is a Vector, not a list:

```
k <- b
```

However, this can work:

```
[ ... | k <- toList b ]
```

Next, the type of `a` and `b` is `Vector Integer`, and the `!` operator takes an `Int`. So you need to convert the index using `fromInteger`:

```
let c = fromList [ a ! fromInteger k | k <- toList b]
```

**Update**

Here is a way to perform the transformation without repeated passes over the arrays:

```
import Data.List

fst3  (b,_,_) = b
third (_,_,a) = a

doit :: Vector Int -> Vector Int -> [[Int]]
doit av bv = [ map third g | g <- groups ]
  where
    triples = zip3 (V.toList bv) [1..] (V.toList av)
    groups = groupBy (\s t -> fst3 s == fst3 t) $ sort triples
```

This is basically a [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) with a groupBy added after the sorting step. The sorting on the triples is done in the canonical way - a lex sort on the first coordinate followed by the second coordinate followed by the third coordinate.

There are other ways to write the expression for `groups`:

```
import Data.Funcition (on)
import GHC.Exts (groupWith)

    ...
    groups = groupBy (on (==) fst3) $ sort triples
    groups = groupWith fst3 triples
```

Note that `groupBy` requires that the triples be sorted whereas `groupWith` doesn't.

Comment: Although this removes the error, the result is not what I aimed for. Each number in `a` should be added to a sub-vector in `c` with the index given in `b`. E.g. a[0] should be in c[b[0]].

Answer (score 0):

With the help of ErikR I came up with this:

```
let c = fromList [fromList [a ! i | i <- [0..Data.Vector.length b-1], (b ! i)==j] | j <- [0..Data.Vector.maximum(b)]]
```

It works but it's not pretty, any better?

Comment: Ok - I understand the transform now. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want would probably be

```
accumulate (flip (:)) (replicate n []) (zip b a)
```

...although you're going to have to explicitly calculate `n`, perhaps as `maximum b + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

With lists this seems to be the logic

```
> map (map snd) $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst) $ sortBy (comparing fst) $ zip b a

[[7],[4,1],[3,8,5],[9,2]]
```